# Bootstrap Datepicker cut off the bottom of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, bootstrap-4

When clicking the datepicker input field, the viewport scrolls down to show the the calendar (as expected), however, the calendar view is cut off from the position at which the viewport was before it scrolled down.

I have tried changing the z-index to both large negative and positive values, it seems to have no effect. I have included a video link also for better demonstration.

[image: screenshot of issue]

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 has-feedback-left">
  <div id="specificday" class="specificday">
      <label for="specificdate" style="font-size: 13px;">What date?</label>
        <div class="input-group date specificdate">
          <input type="text" id="ebaySpecificDate" name="ebaySpecificDate" class="form-control" onkeydown="return false" onchange="return specificDateChanged()" readonly="true"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.input-group.date.specificdate').datepicker({
      format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
      maxViewMode: 1,
      todayBtn: "linked",
      autoclose: true,
      startDate: new Date(),
      todayHighlight: true
}).on('show', function(e){
      $('.datepicker').css("top", $('#ebaySpecificDate').offset().top+35);
      $('.datepicker').css("z-index", 1151);
});
```

**Video**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GzY8msZGy890dc8BHwWUl0zEhIkWGdcI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You have `overflow: hidden` on a parent. The code you posted doesn't include that bit of CSS and is therefore insufficient to repro.. Also note posting videos or images of code and/or code behavior are rarely useful in debugging. What helps is a [mcve] where the issue can actually be inspected.

Comment: The quickest way to fix this is to apply a `bottom-margin` to the datepicker element or a `bottom-padding` to its parent (since it's the last element). Ideally, you want to only apply those values when the picker is opened but even if you apply it permanently, it's not a real UI/UX down-side. Nobody minds a bit of bottom empty space, especially on mobiles. On the contrary.